# Removing a Javascript object from html file

Tags: javascript

Ok so I'm trying to remove an object called Comment from the main Html file. Here's the code:

```
function Comment(message){
var self = this;
var child = null;
var message = message;

var comment = document.createElement("div");
comment.id = "comment";
comment.textContent = message;

var replyField = document.createElement("ul");

var reply = document.createElement("input");
reply.type = "submit";
reply.value = "reply";
comment.appendChild(reply);

var deleteBtn = document.createElement("input");
deleteBtn.type = "submit";
deleteBtn.value = "delete";
deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", function(comment){deleteComment(comment)},false);
comment.appendChild(deleteBtn);
comment.appendChild(replyField);

return comment;
}
function deleteComment(comment){
    var parent = document.getElementById("wall");
    parent.removeChild(comment);
}
```

Once I have created the "Comment object" and prepended it to a `<ul id="wall">`, the delete button does not work for some reason. Can Anyone help me?

here is the html code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery/jquery-1.4.4.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/Comment.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("form#newMessage").submit(function(){
            var message = $("input#newMessageTxt").val();
            var newComment = new Comment(message);
            var commentHtml = newComment.outerHTML;

            $("ul#wall").prepend('<li style="display: none;">'+commentHtml+"</li>");
            $("ul#wall li:first").fadeIn();
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="message">
        <form id="newMessage"&gt;>
            <input type="text" id="newMessageTxt" height="200px" value="Write a message" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue;" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"></button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <ul id="wall">
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: why don't you use JQuery? It will seriously make your life easier

Comment: @Jacob Relkin I made it work but now I cannot use the fadeIn() that I wanted to use inside the html file

Answer (score 2):

I think that this line:

```
deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", function(comment){deleteComment(comment)},false);
```

Should look like this:

```
deleteBtn.onclick = function(e) {
   deleteComment(comment);
   return false;
};
```

EDIT:

**In response to your updated question**, this line:

```
var newComment = new Comment(message);
```

Should be this:

```
var newComment = Comment(message);
```

Comment: `deleteComment(this);` ? `this` is the deleteBtn, you mean `deleteComment(comment);`

Comment: Regarding your update: That does not matter. If you call a function constructor (`new Func()`) and this function returns an object explicitly, then this is totally fine. If the function does not return an object, the object `this` is implicitly returned.

Answer (score 0):

The object passed to an event handler is an `event` object. You cannot define your own parameters in an event handler. So if you define `comment` as parameter, it will refer to the `event` object. Just do remove it or rename it to something else (e.g. `event` ;)):

```
deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){deleteComment(comment)},false);
```

`comment` in the event handler will refer to `comment` defined in the outer function. The function you pass as event handler is a closure.

Side notes:

- Instead of creating a new button, you can save a line of code and clone the previous created button:

  ```
  var deleteBtn = reply.cloneNode();
  deleteBtn.value = "delete";
  ```
- Instead getting the parent by ID, make us of the `parentNode` property:

  ```
  function deleteComment(comment){
      comment.parentNode.removeChild(comment);
  }
  ```
- If you append a new comment directly to `<ul id="wall">` then you create non-valid HTML. A list (`<ul>`) can only contain `<li>` elements.
- To be complete: IE uses a different event model and the method to attach events is called `attachEvent`. See [***quirksmode.org***](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) for more details.

**Update:**

Here is a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4hBSt/1/) which works in all W3C conform browsers ;)

**Update 2:**

As others say, if you use jQuery anyway, use it throughout your code. Here is another example how you can improve your code:

```
function getComment(message) {
    var comment = $('<div />', {
        "class": "comment",
        text: message
    }).append($('<input />', {
        type: "submit",
        val: "reply"
    })).append($('<input/>', {
        type: "submit",
        value: "delete",
        click: function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        }
    })).append('<ul/>');
    return comment;
}

$("form#newMessage").submit(function() {
    var message = $("#newMessageTxt").val();
    $('<li />', {
        style: "display:none"
    }).append(getComment(message)).appendTo('#wall').fadeIn();
    return false;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VjZFk/)

Comment: also note that `addEventListener` will not work prior to IE9 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)

Comment: @Yanick Rochon: Yep, I hope the OP knows that ;)

Comment: I tried this and tested it in Dreamweaver using the live view mode (since it's only front end) and it didn't work.

Comment: @twidizle: See my update. I created a demo and it works. Run it in Firefox or Chrome. If it does not work, the error is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I just posted an update to my question... look at the html code. I don't know why it's not working

Comment: but then how will I be able to use the fadeIn feature from jquery?

Comment: @twidizle: It is because you are not adding the *object* to the DOM, but a string representation of it (with `outerHTML`). Your not doing anything with the *object* you attached the event handler to (`newComment`). If you write `$('<li style="display: none;">').append(newComment).appendTo("ul#wall");` instead, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/4hBSt/5/ But I agree with the others. If you already use jQuery, then use it everywhere. Makes it much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's clearly a problem somewhere else... and since you're not fully using the potential of JQuery, I've taken the liberty of rewriting the code you've provided. Here it is :

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _comment_counter = 0;
        function Comment(msg){

            var comment = $('<div></div>')
                .attr('id', "comment" + (_comment_counter++))
                .text(msg);

            $('<input type="submit"></input>').val('reply')
                .appendTo(comment);
            $('<input type="submit"></input>').val('delete')
                .click(function() { deleteComment(comment); })
                .appendTo(comment);

            $('<ul></ul>')
                .appendTo(comment);

            return comment;
        }
        function addComment(comment) {
            $("ul#wall").prepend(
                $('<li></li>').hide().append(comment).fadeIn()
            );
        }
        function deleteComment(comment){
            comment.parent().fadeOut('normal', function() { $(this).remove(); });
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var _defaultValue = "Write a message";
            $("#newMessageTxt")
                .height("200px")    // ??? use a textarea ?
                .val(_defaultValue)
                .focus(function() {
                    if ($(this).val() == _defaultValue) {
                        $(this).val('');
                    }
                })
                .blur(function() {
                    if(/^\s*$/.test($(this).val())) {
                        $(this).val(_defaultValue);
                    }
                })
            ;

            $("form#newMessage").submit(function(){
                var msg = $("input#newMessageTxt").val();
                if (msg != _defaultValue) {
                    var newComment = new Comment(msg);

                    addComment(newComment);

                    $("input#newMessageTxt").val(_defaultValue);
                }

                return false;
                });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="message">
        <form id="newMessage">
            <input type="text" id="newMessageTxt" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <ul id="wall">
    </ul>
</body>
```

** **TIPS** **

- adopt a coding style, and use it *everywhere*
- if you're using a library, use it or else you're not respecting the point above
- separate code and layout; HTML is a layout, Javascript is code. You shouldn't put socks in your t-shirt drawer...
- if you have a delete function, you should have an add function. This goes for all [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD_%28acronym%29) operations

Now, this code works, you should perhaps start from there.